# Cast my class to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, class

I have an array of objects of my class "Points" and I want to put them on a JSONArray, previusly cast to JSONObject, but I have one problem I can't solve, I can't put my points[] on the JSONObject and I don't know how to do it. I put the code to explain it better.

Principal code:

```
JSONArray jsPoints = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
{
    JSONObject js = new JSONObject(points[i]);
    jsPoints.put(js);
}
```

Point class:

```
public class Point {

String _id; 
String _comment; 
String _calification; 
String _coords;
int _X;
int _Y;

public Point(String id, String comment, String calification, String coords, int x, int y)
{
    _id = id; 
    _comment = comment; 
    _calification = calification; 
    _coords = coords;
    _X = x;
    _Y = y;     
}
}
```

Introducing values into my class:

```
private void createPoints()
{
    points = new Point[drawedInterestPoints.size() / 2]; 
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < drawedInterestPoints.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0)
        {
            points[j] = new Point(pointType.get(i),comments.get(i),calification.get(i),GPScoords.get(i),drawedInterestPoints.get(i),drawedInterestPoints.get(i + 1));
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can tall me what I have to do to put each of my points[] in a JSONObject and then in a JSONArray? Thanks!

Comment: HAve a look at gson, great lib for exactly what u are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try with `GSON`. Do this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
final MyClass myClass = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can not directly cast `JSONArray` to `Points`

what you can do something like following

1. get json as a string
2. de-serialize json to Point using jackson(`ObjectMapper`)

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(points[i]);
```

make no sense; You should put every items of points[] as tag in the jsObject and then insert it in a JsonArray

Try this:

```
public void jsonAsStr() {

    JSONObject mJsonObj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        mJsonObj.put("tag1", true);
        mJsonObj.put("tag2", 120);
        mJsonObj.put("tag3", "Demo");

        JSONArray jsPoints = new JSONArray();
        jsPoints.put(mJsonObj);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Point point = new Point("", "", "", "", 1, 2);
String json = gson.toJson(point);
```